# Download a file from the latest stable Jenkins build

Tags: batch, wget, curl, minecraft, jenkins

Using a batch file and wget/curl, how can I download the Multiverse-Core-.jar from here? http://ci.onarandombox.com/job/Multiverse-Core/lastStableBuild/artifact/target/

I want to use the timestamping option and the "All files in zip" link doesn't work since the "last-modified" header doesn't exist for it. If I use http://ci.onarandombox.com/job/Multiverse-Core/lastStableBuild/artifact/target/Multiverse-Core-2.5.jar, then the timestamping option works, but I want to be able to use the first link and not have to change it every time the version number changes. I've tried

```
wget -r -l 1 -nH -A jar -R *javadoc.jar,*sources.jar http://ci.onarandombox.com/job/Multiverse-Core/lastStableBuild/artifact/target/
```

But it just creates "job\Multiverse-Core\lastStableBuild\artifact\target" in the current directory without the files. Is there something wrong with my script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wget` respects the `robots.txt` file for recursive downloads. And that [file](http://ci.onarandombox.com/robots.txt) prohibits everything (for no good reason AFAICT, as *Build Now* requires to be `POST`ed in Jenkins, at least in recent versions).

---

Jenkins has an API. Several objects, including builds, have API endpoints. In this case, `http://ci.onarandombox.com/job/Multiverse-Core/lastStableBuild/api/`.

You could query `http://ci.onarandombox.com/job/Multiverse-Core/lastStableBuild/api/xml` or `http://ci.onarandombox.com/job/Multiverse-Core/lastStableBuild/api/json` and parse the returned text for the `artifacts` element. The `tree` argument allows filtering, like e.g. in `http://ci.onarandombox.com/job/Multiverse-Core/lastStableBuild/api/xml?tree=artifacts%5BrelativePath%5D`:

```
<freeStyleBuild>
<artifact>
<relativePath>target/Multiverse-Core-2.5-javadoc.jar</relativePath>
</artifact>
<artifact>
<relativePath>target/Multiverse-Core-2.5-sources.jar</relativePath>
</artifact>
<artifact>
<relativePath>target/Multiverse-Core-2.5.jar</relativePath>
</artifact>
</freeStyleBuild>
```

Alternatively, use XPath for more powerful filtering, but note that in a recent security update, some functionality (like `text()`) was disabled. Example: `http://ci.onarandombox.com/job/Multiverse-Core/lastStableBuild/api/xml?xpath=/freeStyleBuild/artifact/relativePath&wrapper=artifacts`

From the command line, you can parse the XML e.g. using a recent version of `xmllint`, or, in the Xpath example, just ignore the text and select the file names.

Comment: Could you perhaps show me how I use this to get curl/wget to download just the Multiverse-Core.jar in a batch script? I'm using Windows 7 if that matters.

Comment: @Craft1n3ss I don't know enough batch.

Comment: Thanks for the information anyway. I can probably do it myself if I search around or ask another question. I'd give you an upvote, but I don't have enough reputation (this was my first question).

Comment: Got it! using `FOR /F "tokens=14 delims=<>" %%a IN ('curl -g "http://ci.onarandombox.com/job/Multiverse-Core/lastStableBuild/api/xml?tree=artifacts[fileName]"') DO ECHO %%a` will echo the exact name of the file I want. Thanks for the help.